# Cual es la manera mas optima de almacenar meses en una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, diseño, ingenieria-del-software

Estoy haciendo un sistema de contratación y los contratos pueden extenderse máximo hasta un (1) año por lo que el usuario solo va a insertar el día de creación del contrato y los meses de duración del contrato.

Como se ve en la imagen, cree una columna tipo enum para un rango de valores del 1 hasta el 12 para posteriormente calcular las fechas de vencimiento de contrato  por medio de PHP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo hice de esta forma ya que el tipo de dato `INT(2)` o `VARCHAR(2)` podría insertar valores fuera del rango [1-12]. También podría declarar el dato tipo `DATE` insertando bajo el siguiente formato `0000-03-00` (que sería "Marzo") pero como pienso que la base de datos no debería realizar estos cálculos me decante por el `ENUM`.

¿Es esa una manera adecuada de hacerlo? ¿Cómo podría hacerse mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mi la mejor forma es trabajar directamente con fechas, en la parte del cliente me imagino que es cuando obtienes el valor de "meses" o mejor dicho de tiempo de la duración del contrato. Si por ejemplo, hoy es *25/01/2018* y la persona selecciona 6 meses de duración, seria el *25/07/2018*. Para obtener eso puedes obtener la fecha actual y hacer algo asi:

```
$cantidadMeses = 6; //por ejemplo
$fechaActual = date("Y-m-d");
$finContrato = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaActual)) . " + ". $cantidadMeses ." month");
```

Y guardar `$finContrato` en la base de datos, con esa fecha, hacer los calculos pertinentes.

Answer (score 1):

No te compliques la vida. Tú mismo has dado la respuesta, cuando dices: *por lo que el usuario solo va a insertar **el día de creación del contrato** y **los meses de duración** del contrato.*  De ahí se deduce que vas a necesitar dos datos:

- inicio del contrato
- fin del contrato

Aunque sólo vayas a necesitar calcular los meses, no importa, **¡usa dos campos `DATE` o `DATETIME`!** y a partir de ahí calcula lo que quieras. Los datos serán más fáciles de insertar y mantener.

Por ejemplo, para la inserción, si quieres, en la interfaz gráfica puedes pedir una fecha de inicio y un número entero de duración del contrato y a partir de esos dos datos puedes calcular y guardar en la base de datos la fecha de fin.

Y además, ¿quién te dice que el modelo de datos no va a evolucionar más adelante y te van a pedir fechas precisas? ¿Cómo las vas a capturar si tienes varios miles o millones de registros con esa información guardada en números enteros?

Guarda los datos como lo que son en realidad: si son fechas, guarda fechas y a partir de tus datos calcula lo que tengas que calcular.

No intentes guarda en tu base de datos una información que forma más bien parte de la lógica del programa (la cual puede variar). Las bases de datos son para guardar datos, basándose en la realidad.

Comment: bueno es que mi jefe de programacion de un sermon de "normalizacion de datos" asi que quise preguntar en la comunidad porque tengo la misma opinión de usted.

Comment: @Sr. K Precisamente la *normalización* sería algo que habría que aplicar más adelante si diseñas tus datos del modo planteado en la pregunta, para corregir errores de diseño debido a que se necesita información más precisa o a que todo se ha complicado porque el modelo de datos evolucionó y no se previó esa posible evolución. Eso suele pasar cuando tú quieres reflejar un problema de lógica o de interfaz gráfica en los datos mismos. Ese es un gravísimo error de diseño.